# how can we delete one value out of two values from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to this?I have a table with two rows and 1 column.Both rows have same value.no primary key is there.can we delete 1 row?

Comment: use LIMIT 1 on the end of your query

Comment: You should consider adding a surrogate key.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with `ROW_NUMBER()` and a `common table expression`:

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by id order by id) rn 
  from yourtable)
delete from cte
where rn = 1;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef244/1)

Comment: i think rn change to rn > 1 is better, in order to handle more than 1 duplicates values

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using RANK() function.

or you can use TOP keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can get fancy and use cte to delete one but if they are the same value (and the table is as simple as you're describing it), you can also delete both and add one back. Much simpler.

Surrogate Key anyone?